# Checkbox click with Firefox using selenium 3 not working?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have below code to uncheck check box when it is selected, but when i run test  i could see checkbox is unchecked for less than few seconds and again it is auto checked after less than few seconds. But I have no issues with Chrome and IE.
I am using Firefox Quantum(58.0.2 64-bit) and rememberMe is checkbox id.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rememberMe']")).isSelected()) {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rememberMe']")).click(); --> here it should uncheck check box.
       Thread.sleep(6000);          
}
```

I have used all other options like wait on element, send keys etc. Could some one please point me in right direction?

Comment: The _right direction_ would be: **Never** (that spells NEVER) use `Thread.sleep`. It is just a waste of time. Try something smart like `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By locator)` and then click to uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more like this

```
WebElement checkbox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("rememberMe")));
if (checkbox.isSelected())
{
    checkbox.click();
}
```

It waits for the element to be clickable then clicks it if it's selected.

Comment: Thanks for your response JeffC. I have tested with your code, I could see checkbox is unchecked for less than 1 second and again checkbox gets clicked by itself one more time and there is check in checkbox . Is could be firefox browser issue?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?